# How to use VirtualBox's DHCP server for a pfSense guest machine so that other guest machine's within the internal network can connect to it

Tags: networking, virtualbox, firewall, dhcp, pfsense

My goal is to have pfSense set up using VirtualBox's DHCP server. This is so that it could be connected to the other guest machines on the internal network. Currently, all my other guest machines (not including pfSense) are connected to each other on an internal network within VirtualBox.

My goal is to take the guest machines and make pfSense their default gateway so they have internet access through pfSense.

The problem is that pfSense already assigned the LAN interface with its own IP from the DHCP server. I want it so that the LAN interface is assigned an IP from VirtualBox's DHCP server. Also, for my own reasons, this all has to be down through the shell on pfSense.

I have already disabled DHCP using `pfSsh.php playback disabledhcpd`, but don't know how to assign the LAN interface the IP from my own DHCP server.

Within pfSense, I am only able to assign static  IPs.

How do I assign the LAN interface an IP from VirtualBox's DHCP server so that it is part of the internal network?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Further Clarified

Answer (score 0):

By design Oracle VirtualBox arranges the network configuration for the VMs.

Having a pfSense inside VirtualBox is not a bad idea though but there are a few things that should be known before somebody starts implementing a router in a virtualized environment especially in desktop virtualization environment.

Why am I saying this ?

There are preconfigured network settings that make the things easier if you just need to deploy a guest quicly or not the network configuration is your hobby.
Of course in this case you also need to understand the basics and in addition need to understand the product implementation specialties. This is why the manual is for.

Check this reference: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

After you got familiarized yourself in the topic I would recommend to create a VM in VirtualBox and add two NICs

1. Bridged card.
2. Internal card.

Your bridged interface is your physical card and VirtualBox gives it to the pfSense. Your internal card will have only guest internal traffic. When you create more guests in your VirtualBox you need to add them only Internal cards.

If you configured your pfSense (sorry but this would be to long to express and this is a different topic anyhow) and you can see the IP address on the WAN interface you can start to configure your DHCP to your LAN interface.

To do this you need to create a VM with graphical interface capability in your box because GUI will not be available from the WAN interface. And configuring DHCP is far more easier on GUI.

When your pfSense is up and running and you create a new VM in your box it will get IP from your DHCP. (But this is a different topic again.)

I reproduced this please check the screenshot below. You can see the connection marked with white.

[image: Virtualized pfSense in Oracle VirtualBox.]